# RegEx - How to delete everything before the third empty space in a Notepad++ line?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm having trouble figuring out the correct regular expression formula to delete all characters before the third empty space in a Notepad++ line. I have text that reads this:

kea k3fi ifea1k monkey
k22a kfea.f fkaa99 parrot
23 ma feaj bear

I want the text to be manipulated so it reads this:

monkey
parrot
bear

Does anyone have an idea? Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Edit >> Problem solved. Thank you all for your help! I wish I was as smart as you guys, haha. Cheers!

Comment: Something like: ^([^ ]* ){3}

Comment: @sweersz if your problem is solved you can accept an answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use:

```
^(.*? ){3}
```

And leave ***"Replace with:"*** with *nothing*. This will turn:

```
kea k3fi ifea1k monkey
k22a kfea.f fkaa99 parrot
23 ma feaj bear
```

Into:

```
monkey
parrot
bear
```

---

On the other hand, if your file is like:

```
kea k3fi ifea1k monkey monkey monkey monkey monkey
k22a kfea.f fkaa99 parrot parrot parrot parrot parrot
23 ma feaj bear bear bear bear bear
```

The regex above is too simple. You'll have to use the regex:

```
^((.*? ){3})(.*?)$
```

And leave ***"Replace with:"*** with `$3`.

This will turn the file above into:

```
monkey monkey monkey monkey monkey
parrot parrot parrot parrot parrot
bear bear bear bear bear
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to replace:

```
^([^ ]* ){3}
```

or:

```
^[^ ]* [^ ]* [^ ]*
```

with the empty string

Comment: @Bohemian, the brackets mark spaces, so I use them with whitespace.

Comment: You would be better to use `\s` than clutter up the regex with brackets. Regex are hard to read at the best of times. Perhaps I was presumptuous to edit, rather than comment though. I was trying to improve it. In general, it's OK to use a space as-is; many regexes I've seen use them.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is:

```
^([^ ]+ ){3}
```

start with 3 none spaced words three times.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
find: ^([^ ]+ ){3}(.+)$
replace: $2
```

and push replaceAll!

Comment: Whoa, you all rock. Thanks SO much for the help! :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deal also with tabulations or other space characters

```
find:    ^(\S+\s+){3}
replace: "nothing"
```

`\s` stands any space character
`\S` stands for non space character